# Weird/strange shading on flat surface

Tags: modeling, eevee-render-engine

Why is there these strange shadings?

I've checked and I don't have any overlapping vertices, and the normals are all pointing the correct direction.

I think this started happening after I deleted a loop on the inside of the long straps, but when
I realized it, I wasn't able to control z far back enough, and I accidentally already saved after I deleted the loop.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried resetting your normals?

Comment: Uh I alrdy did.

Comment: Would you be okay with uploading your blend file?

Comment: Yea, I'll cut off the other parts.

Comment: How do I upload the file..?

Comment: Ok done........

Comment: Ok, so I noticed that turning off smooth shading under vertex data panel helped, got rid of the weird shading. Then I tried resetting the vectors to make the sharps do their job and it turned out fine. Here's a fixed blend file. https://blend-exchange.com/b/M31RyaVG

Comment: WHAT IS THIS DARK MAGIC. omg omg wow thank you so much thanks thanks

Comment: What's the vertex data panel? And how does resetting the vectors work, is it different from the normals?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122392/discussion-between-nascent-space-and-jerry-w).